# CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime environment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.crypto.hdwrCCA.provider.IBMJCECCA

Tags: java, ssl, zos, zosmf, zowe

I am starting a Zowe 0.9.1 instance on z/OS 2.3; z/OSMF is already up and running.  During the initialization of the Explorer Server (ZOWESVR) the following message is being issued in the stdout:

> CWWKE0018E: An exception occurred while launching the runtime
>   environment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.ibm.crypto.hdwrCCA.provider.IBMJCECCA (initialization failure)

As a result, no Sockets are being opened for the Liberty server (7080 or 7443).  The trace and log files for the Explorer Server provide no additional information as to the nature of the failure.

z/OSMF is running correctly and all sockets are opened and is running the same instance of Liberty which is 17.0.0.2.

Have others experienced this / have a resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the two processes (z/OSMF and ZOWESVR) being started with different build levels of Java.  This resulted in the shared class cache having different versions of the IBMJCECCA class.

The fix was to ensure that Zowe is installed and started with the same Java JDK as z/OSMF.

Comment: Nice :). You should mark your answer as the correct one so the thread will be marked "solved."

Comment: Thanks @LayneBernardo need to wait two days :)